# Best data analysis method to predict where a certain value will fit in a dataset

Tags: python, data-analysis, weka, prediction, orange

I am using a very small dataset to teach myself predictive data analytics.
I am using both Weka and Orange to try and solve this issue.

To start with I am using this csv file to train the system:

```
gender,weight
M,82
F,71
M,90
F,76
M,88
F,56
M,100
F,63
M,84
F,79
M,92
F,66
```

You will notice that all the F values are below 80 and all the M values are above 80.

I then have this data file:

```
weight, gender
70,,
100,,
69,,
76,,
99,,
```

Notice that the 'gender' value is missing.

I would like to come up with a system that will read the data file and place either an M or F into the gender field based on some data analysis.

I looked into Linear Regression but that involves a relationship between two moving values (as X increases - so does Y)

I then looked into K-Clustering but all that did was show me two clusters with M > 80 and F < 80

Please can you advise a system I can use to try and apply some predictions to my dataset?

Much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like something a [decision tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree) can do easily.
I looked up a [weka tutorial](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2020/03/decision-tree-weka-no-coding/) for you since I've never used it. But the concepts are the same.

Comment: Thank you. Although I could not glean anything useful from the Weka tutorial (it showed how to load a training file and view the tree output - which I already knew - however, I could not see where to load the datafile that required the analysis). Nonetheless, I looked into decision trees and used a combination of the tree-treeview-predictions widget set in Orange and managed to get the solution I wanted. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Going off Ilyas's answer, here's [python's scikit-learn documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html). I'd suggest checking out the classification entries in the supervised learning doc for python's scikit-learn, [found here.](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/supervised_learning.html)

Answer (score 0):

Using Weka, as [Ilyas Moutawwakil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68982364/4698227) suggested, you can do something like this:

First, convert your data to [ARFF](https://waikato.github.io/weka-wiki/formats_and_processing/arff_stable/) (the ARFF format specifies values for categorical in its header to avoid problems with CSV files and potentially missing/additional values):

Your training data:

```
@relation train

@attribute weight numeric
@attribute gender {F,M}

@data
82,M
71,F
90,M
76,F
88,M
56,F
100,M
63,F
84,M
79,F
92,M
66,F
```

Your data that you want predictions for:

```
@relation predict

@attribute weight numeric
@attribute gender {F,M}

@data
70,?
100,?
69,?
76,?
99,?
```

Then you can use a decision tree algorithm, like [J48](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/trees/J48.html) to train on your training data and generate predictions on your other dataset (adjust paths to `weka.jar` and your datasets, of course):

```
java -cp weka.jar weka.classifiers.trees.J48 -t train.arff -T predict.arff -p 1
```

**NB:** With `-p 1` we are adding the first attribute (`weight`) to the output.

If you want the predictions to be output in a [CSV](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/evaluation/output/prediction/CSV.html) file (`predictions.csv`), you can do something like this:

```
java -cp weka.jar weka.classifiers.trees.J48 -t train.arff -T predict.arff -classifications "weka.classifiers.evaluation.output.prediction.CSV -p 1 -file predictions.csv -suppress"
```

The `predictions.csv` file will look like this:

```
inst#,actual,predicted,error,prediction,weight
1,1:?,1:F,,1,70
2,1:?,2:M,,1,100
3,1:?,1:F,,1,69
4,1:?,1:F,,1,76
5,1:?,2:M,,1,99
```